# Python multiprocessing not working concurrently, but separately

Tags: python, multithreading, scripting

I'm having a little bit of a confusion with the `multiprocessing` module in python. So far in my code, I want to create a separate process for the generate_pings() function, so then that process runs independent of the main process in the main function.

But when I print this out, all of the generate_pings() output comes first, then the count to 999. How do I get them to run at the same time? I've tried using the threading module but it confused me a little bit.

Also when exactly do I use the .join()?

Thanks

```
import multiprocessing
#generate pings so packets are moving, have this running in a separate thread
def generate_pings():
    count = 0
    while count < 1:


        ping_respose = subprocess.call(["ping -c 50 -i 0.1 weissmanscore.com"], shell=True)    

        count+=1
    return


def main():
    print "welcome"
    try:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=generate_pings)
        p.start()
    except:
        print "Error: unable to start thread"
    p.join()
    i = 0
    while i < 1000:
        print i
        i+=1




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `join()` waits for the process to finish, so by calling it immediately after you create it, you're not doing much in parallel. Move it to the end of `main`.

Comment: I moved it to the end of `main` but now it just prints 0-999 and then calls the pings from generate_pings() are happening. They don't seem to be working parallel still.

Comment: I'd imagine Python can print `i` 1000 times before the ping gets a result back. Try adding a call to [`time.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) in the loop in `main`.

Comment: You are 100% right. Thank you, don't know why I never thought of that! Adding a `time.sleep` in the main showed that they are running concurrently. Thanks